# Function linear in one variable and quadratic concave on another, is concave in jointly?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a function $f(x,y,z)$. $f$ is convex with respect to $x$, and linear with respect to $y$. Also, it is quadratic concave with respect to $z$. I want to solve the following optimization problem: 
\begin{align}
    \min_{x\in C} \max_{y\in D_y} \max_z f(x,y,z)
\end{align}
My question is can I assume that this problem is concave with respect to $(y,z)$?
Let $g(y,z) = \min_{x\in C} f(x,y,z)$. Function $g(u)$, where $u=(y,z)$ is concave? 
What if $f(x,y,z) = f_1(x,y) + f_2(x,z)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you may not. Suppose $f(x,y,z) = -yz^2$, with $D_y = \mathbb{R_+}$, then the Hessian is:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & -2z \\ -2z & -2y\end{pmatrix}$$
which is indefinite for $z \neq 0$, since the eigenvalues are $-y \pm \sqrt{y² + 4z²}$

Comment: What if we know that $f(x,y,z)=f_1(x,y) + f_2(x,z)$, that is we don't have any multiplication with the variables $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Or I should I ask another question?

Comment: Then $f$ is jointly concave, since the hessian w.r.t. $y$ and $z$ is a diagonal matrix with elements $d^2 f / dy^2$ and $d^2 f / dz^2$, which are both negative due to the concavity assumption.

Comment: I don't understand, how you assume from hessian of f with respect to $y$ and $z$, concavity of function $g(u)$, in the question?

Comment: Could you please provide a more exact proof?

Comment: A function is concave if its Hessian is negative semidefinite.

Comment: I know, but minimzation with respect to $x$ doesn't change function?

Comment: Sorry, hadn't seen the minimization, and only concluded concavity of $f(x,y,z)$ w.r.t. $(y,z)$. Fortunately, the minimum of a collection of concave functions is still concave (like the maximum of convex functions is convex), so $g$ is concave.